# DataGridColumnHeader ContextMenu programmatically

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I have this code in View.cs

```
var contextMenu = this.dataGridFacade.GiveContextMenuForDataGrid(this.DataGridAllJobs);

this.DataGridAllJobs.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

But I want to add this context menu for header only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just have to retrieve the [DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheaderspresenter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of your DataGrid and set its ContextMenu.

```
var contextMenu = this.dataGridFacade.GiveContextMenuForDataGrid(this.DataGridAllJobs);
var columnHeadersPresenter = this.DataGridAllJobs.SafeFindDescendant<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>(ip => ip.Name == "PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter");
if (columnHeadersPresenter != null)
{
    columnHeadersPresenter.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
}
```

And here is the SafeFindDescendant extension method :

```
public static class Visual_ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the first Descendant of the currren Visual in the VisualTree matching the given predicate
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="this">The current Visual.</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">An optional predicate that the descendant have to satisfy.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T SafeFindDescendant<T>(this Visual @this, Predicate<T> predicate = null) where T : Visual
    {
        T result = null;
        if (@this == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // iterate on VisualTree children thanks to VisualTreeHelper
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(@this);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var currentChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(@this, i);

            var typedChild = currentChild as T;
            if (typedChild == null)
            {
                // recursive search
                result = ((Visual)currentChild).SafeFindDescendant<T>(predicate);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (predicate == null || predicate(typedChild))
                {
                    result = typedChild;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thnink you win this 50 reputation points. My so hard earned 50 points..) Why have you waited till I post it with bounty? =) Thx for you answer! )

Comment: Sorry I did not see this one sooner :) I try to answer as much WPF questions as possible, but can't answer all. However I always get a look at bounties :) Don't forget to mark as Answer if it solved your problem !

Comment: Upped your question as it was interresting. That will be 10rep less lost for your bounty ;)

Comment: Thanks for  up votes! ) And where have you find this solution? I mean the opportunity to find descendants this way with exetions etc..

Comment: That's something I've been doing for a long time ! I just posted this method and a similar one to find ancestors on my blog though.

Comment: Please consider flaggin as answer ;)

Comment: Sure - I only want to wait some more days to give the other users the opportunity to post their answers too )

Comment: No problem ^^ Happy adventures with WPF !