# WPF DataGridColumnHeader: ContextMenu disappears after hiding/re-showing column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to come up with a System.Windows.Interactivity.Behaviour that, when applied to a WPF DataGrid, adds a context menu (or items to an existing context menu) that allow users to show or hide columns.

I came up with a solution that *almost* works very well.
Everything works just as expected - until you hide and then re-show a column. Once becoming visible again, the contextmenu just seems to disappear, right-clicking on the column doesn't do anything anymore.

Code is below, verbalyl what I'm doing:

1. On attaching the behavior, I start listening to the DataGrid "Loaded" event
2. In the Loaded event, I find all DataGridColumnHeader descendants of the DataGrid
3. For each of these, I generate an individual context menu and attach it to the DataGridColumnHeader
4. For each context menu, I generate one menu item per column, and assign a command to it that, upon execution, sets the DataGridColumn's visibility to Visible or Hidden

I've stripped down the code to a minimum example for the simplest case: To test this, simply apply that behavior to a DataGrid that doesn't have a ContextMenu assigned currently.

```
public class DgColumnBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected ICommand ToggleColumnVisibilityCmd;
    protected DataGrid _AssociatedObject;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.ToggleColumnVisibilityCmd = new DelegateCommand<DataGridColumn>(ToggleColumnVisibilityCmdExecute);
        this._AssociatedObject = (DataGrid)this.AssociatedObject;

        Observable.FromEventPattern(this._AssociatedObject, "Loaded")
            .Take(1)
            .Subscribe(x => _AssociatedObject_Loaded());

        base.OnAttached();
    }

    void _AssociatedObject_Loaded()
    {
        var columnHeaders = this._AssociatedObject.SafeFindDescendants<DataGridColumnHeader>();  // see second code piece for the SafeFindDescendants extension method

        foreach (var columnHeader in columnHeaders)
        {
            EnsureSeparateContextMenuFor(columnHeader);

            if (columnHeader.ContextMenu.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                // ContextMenu has an ItemsSource, so need to add items to that -
                // ommitted though as irrelevant for example
            }
            else
            {
                // No ItemsSource assigned to the Menu, so we can just add directly

                foreach (var item in CreateMenuItemsFor(columnHeader))
                    columnHeader.ContextMenu.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /// Ensures that the columnHeader ...
    /// A) has a ContextMenu, and
    /// B) that is has an individual context menu, i.e. one that isn't shared with any other DataGridColumnHeaders.
    /// 
    /// I'm doing that as in practice, I'm adding some further items that are specific to each column, so I can't have a shared context menu
    private void EnsureSeparateContextMenuFor(DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader)
    {
        if (columnHeader.ContextMenu == null)
        {
            columnHeader.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        else
        {
            // clone the existing menu
            // ommitted as irrelevant for example
        }
    }

    /// Creates one menu item for each column of the underlying DataGrid to toggle that column's visibility
    private IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> CreateMenuItemsFor(DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader)
    {
        foreach (var column in _AssociatedObject.Columns)
        {
            var item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = String.Format("Toggle visibility for {0}", column.Header);
            item.Command = ToggleColumnVisibilityCmd;
            item.CommandParameter = column;

            yield return item;
        }
    }

    // Gets executed when the user clicks on one of the ContextMenu items
    protected void ToggleColumnVisibilityCmdExecute(DataGridColumn column)
    {
        bool isVisible = (column.Visibility == Visibility.Visible);
        Visibility newVisibility = (isVisible) ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
        column.Visibility = newVisibility;
    }
}
```

The SafeFindDescendants extension method is heavily based on the one from here: [DataGridColumnHeader ContextMenu programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746689/datagridcolumnheader-contextmenu-programmatically)

```
public static class Visual_ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SafeFindDescendants<T>(this Visual @this, Predicate<T> predicate = null) where T : Visual
    {
        if (@this != null)
        {
            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(@this);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var currentChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(@this, i);

                var typedChild = currentChild as T;
                if (typedChild == null)
                {
                    var result = ((Visual)currentChild).SafeFindDescendants<T>(predicate);

                    foreach (var r in result)
                        yield return r;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (predicate == null || predicate(typedChild))
                    {
                        yield return typedChild;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what's going on. Why does the context menu seem to be removed after hiding/re-showing a column?!

Appreciate any ideas! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a quick and dirty Fix. It works, but it isn't pretty. Maybe someone can think of a better solution.

Essentially, each time the visibility of a DataGridColumn item changes to hidden/collapsed, I retrieve its DataGridColumnHeader and store the associated context menu in a cache.
And each time the visibility changes back to visible, I'm listening to the next DataGrid LayoutUpdated event (to ensure the visual tree has been built), retrieve the DataGridColumnHeader again - which will incoveniently be a different instance than the original one - and set its context menu to the cached one.

```
    protected IDictionary<DataGridColumn, ContextMenu> _CachedContextMenues = new Dictionary<DataGridColumn, ContextMenu>();

protected void ToggleColumnVisibilityCmdExecute(DataGridColumn column)
    {
        bool isVisible = (column.Visibility == Visibility.Visible);
        Visibility newVisibility = (isVisible) ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;


        if(newVisibility != Visibility.Visible)
        {
            // We're hiding the column, so we'll cache its context menu so for re-use once the column
            // becomes visible again

            var contextMenu = _AssociatedObject.SafeFindDescendants<DataGridColumnHeader>(z => z.Column == column).Single().ContextMenu;
            _CachedContextMenues.Add(column, contextMenu);
        }
        if(newVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            // The column just turned visible again, so we set its context menu to the
            // previously cached one

            Observable
                .FromEventPattern(_AssociatedObject, "LayoutUpdated")
                .Take(1)
                .Select(x => _AssociatedObject.SafeFindDescendants<DataGridColumnHeader>(z => z.Column == column).Single())
                .Subscribe(x =>
                    {
                        var c = x.Column;
                        var cachedMenu = _CachedContextMenues[c];
                        _CachedContextMenues.Remove(c);
                        x.ContextMenu = cachedMenu;
                    });
        }

        column.Visibility = newVisibility;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already found a better solution?

I have a new DataGrid class, so "this" is the actual Instance of a DataGrid!
This is my solution (I'm also listen on the LayoutUpdated event):

```
this.LayoutUpdated += (sender, args) =>
{
    foreach (DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader in GetVisualChildCollection<DataGridColumnHeader>(this))
    {
        if(columnHeader.ContextMenu == null)
            ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(columnHeader, _ContextMenu);
    }
};



    public static List<T> GetVisualChildCollection<T>(object parent) where T : Visual
    {
        List<T> visualCollection = new List<T>();
        GetVisualChildCollection(parent as DependencyObject, visualCollection);
        return visualCollection;
    }

    private static void GetVisualChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> visualCollection) where T : Visual
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is T)
            {
                visualCollection.Add(child as T);
            }
            else if (child != null)
            {
                GetVisualChildCollection(child, visualCollection);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, no better solution yet unfortuantely. The fix I posted above seems to work ok so far though.
Re your code: Keep in mind LayoutUpdated gets called a LOT - e.g. tons of times while resizing columns etc. I only start listening to the first event occurrence when needed (=> the visibility of a column changed) and then unsubscribe from the event again (".Take(1)"). If you see any performance issues with your solution, you may want to do something similar; implementation depends a little on your project and requirements

Comment: Thank you for your hint! You were right, it is called very often! I'm listening now when the Visibility is changed (menuItem.Click()) and deregister the event after it is called (what is immediately afterwards).